# MVC WebAPI Data Annotation Error Message Empty String

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have implemented an OWIN self-hosted webapi and am trying to use data annotations and an ActionFilterAttribute to return formatted errors to the user. I have set custom error messages on the data annotation but when I try to retrieve the message from the ModelState it is always an empty string (shown in image below).

[image]

Model:

```
public class JobPointer
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "JobId Required")]
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class ModelValidationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) return;
        string errors = actionContext.ModelState.SelectMany(state => state.Value.Errors).Aggregate("", (current, error) => current + (error.ErrorMessage + ". "));

        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
    }

}
```

Endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage DescribeJob(JobPointer jobId)
{

   Job job = _jobhelper.GetJob(jobId.JobId);
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, job);
}
```

Request Body:

```
{

}
```

Response:

```
Status Code: 400
{
  "Message": ". "
}
```

If I change error.Message in ModelValidationFilter to error.Exception.Message I get back the default validation error:

```
Status Code: 400
{
  "Message": "Required property 'JobId' not found in JSON. Path '', line 3, position 2.. "
}
```

Comment: can you add your API call and full response details? do you get a 400 bad request with empty response. the little snapshot shows a JSON exception for jobid.. try to make the field nullable (Guid?) and try again. in any case, please provide more details. controller action method, maybe a fiddler request/response.

Comment: I am sending a blank json block , I will add the code for the endpoint being called. I properly get 400 bad request and I can return the exception message properly that states "Required property 'JobId' not found..." but i would like to return my custom message.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just had this problem and found the solution myself.

As you no doubt discovered, as Guid is a non-nullable type [Required] produces an unfriendly error message (I assume because the JSON parser picks it up before actually getting the model validation).

You can get around this by making the Guid nullable...

```cs
public class JobPointer
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "JobId Required")]
    public Guid? JobId { get; set; }
}
```

... however, this is not a viable option in all cases (as in my case), so I ended up writing my own validation attribute that would check the property against it's Empty declaration...

```
public class IsNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        if (value == null) return false;

        var valueType = value.GetType();
        var emptyField = valueType.GetField("Empty");

        if (emptyField == null) return true;

        var emptyValue = emptyField.GetValue(null);

        return !value.Equals(emptyValue);

    }
}
```

You could then implement like...

```cs
public class JobPointer
{
    [IsNotEmpty(ErrorMessage = "JobId Required")]
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
}
```